# add li in ul using main div ID

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

```
<div id="my_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi chzn-container-active" style="width: 200px;" title="">

      <div style="left: 0px; width: 198px; top: 22px;" class="chzn-drop">
             <ul class="chzn-results">
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_0">ABC</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_1">DEF</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_2">GHI</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_3">JKL</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_4">MNO</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_5">PQR</li>
             </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div id="geoRange_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi chzn-container-active" style="width: 200px;" title="">

      <div style="left: 0px; width: 198px; top: 22px;" class="chzn-drop">
             <ul class="chzn-results">
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_0">ABC</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_1">DEF</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_2">GHI</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_3">JKL</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_4">MNO</li>
                <li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_5">PQR</li>
             </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

The first main div `id=my_chzn` and the second main `div id=geoRange_chzn` and other things are same; How can I add `li` based upon the main div ID, in the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
$('#my_chzn .chzn-drop ul').append('<li class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_6">STU</li>');
```

to add a `li` in the `ul` inside the div of class `chzn-drop` inside the div with id `my_chzn`.

To add the `li` to the other div, change the id like this :

```
$('#geoRange_chzn .chzn-drop ul').append('<li/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "geoRange_chzn" // here is the id only
$("#"+s+" *").each( function(e) {
    var s = $(this).prop("tagName");
    if(s=="UL") {
        $(this).append('<li style="" class="active-result" id="geoRange_chzn_o_5">PQR</li>');
    }
});
```

​
if you have only id then you can use above technique to append to UL element.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH2TG/)

Comment: hope you want this ;) you will need only main div ID!

Comment: Don't iterate over elements to find the one with a given tag, use jQuery.

Comment: @dystroy he said he wants to append li only with main div id.... I used many ways to get it working with id only but can't figure out then i used this ;)